# JAXB XSD Elements (Basic)

Tags: xsd, jaxb, uri

I want to bind the incoming XML to a JavaType

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apiKeys uri="http://api-keys">
<apiKey uri="http://api-keys/1933"/>
<apiKey uri="http://api-keys/19334"/>
</apiKeys>
```

I wish to use JAXB, so I have defined an XSD. My XSD is incorrect, and the created objects - whilst being created - are empty.

My XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="apiKeys" type="ApiKeysResponseInfo2" />

<xsd:complexType name="ApiKeysResponseInfo2">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="uri" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="apiKey" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>  
</xsd:schema>
```

Obviously my element definitions are wrong. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to use JAXB, so I have defined an XSD.

JAXB does not require an XML schema.  We designed it to start from Java objects, the ability to generate an annotated model from an XML schema was added as a convenience mechanism.

---

> I want to bind the incoming XML to a JavaType

You could use the object model below:

**ApiKeys**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class ApiKeys {

    private String uri;
    private List<ApiKey> apiKey;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public List<ApiKey> getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(List<ApiKey> apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

}
```

**ApiKey**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class ApiKey {

    private String uri;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ApiKeys.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14643483/input.xml");
        ApiKeys apiKeys = (ApiKeys) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(apiKeys, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Woo, thanks for for that Blaise - I'll give it a go. My motivation is actually to work with Json, so all I actually want is the Jaxb objects anyway, and wont be maintaining an XSD.

Comment: My current Jaxb objects do look like yours, but Ill tweek a few things and retest. The (translation) part I don't understand relates to  <apiKey uri="http://api-keys/1933"/> - whereas if the XML where something like <apiKey>http://api-keys/1933"</apiKey> - I could see how that is being mapped..

Comment: @Damo - By `translation` part do you mean to JSON?

Comment: I'm more used to working with XML than JSON, my plan is to create the JAXB objects and verify their correctness by binding XML to them, then swap the incoming data representation to be Json (I'm writing a rest client)

Comment: My translation comment is to do with the funky syntax of <apiKey uri="api-keys/1933"/>; where this element has an "apiKey" "part" and a "uri" "part" - so confused as to what the Jaxb field these "parts" map to looks like. That said, I now have something working. I tweaked my XSD- which creates Jaxb objects that look more like yours. I think I have enough info to review and figure out how all this is happening now, unless you can help me more with my translation query. Thanks.